# Getting `object scala in compiler mirror not found issue` while running the springboot application using jar but not with classpath

Tags: java, spring-boot, scala, spring-boot-maven-plugin, scala-compiler

I have a multi-module application which has a java HTTP application (springboot, java 11) in one module and scala code in the second module.

The second module is included as a dependency in the first module as code in the second module needs to get invoked on REST invocations.

Here is a [minimal project](https://github.com/AlokhPD11/scala-compiler-issue) to reproduce the issue.

Steps to reproduce the issue

```
mvn clean compile
java -jar scala-compiler-issue-service/target/scala-compiler-issue-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The above command to run the application fails on initialisation of the scala compiler.

```
Caused by: scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object scala in compiler mirror not found.
        at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:24) ~[scala-reflect-2.12.16.jar!/:na]
        at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.notFound(MissingRequirementError.scala:25) ~[scala-reflect-2.12.16.jar!/:na]
        at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.$anonfun$getModuleOrClass$5(Mirrors.scala:61) ~[scala-reflect-2.12.16.jar!/:na]
        at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getPackage(Mirrors.scala:61) ~[scala-reflect-2.12.16.jar!/:na]
```

Interesting thing here is once we run the application using -cp command and pass the scala jars in classpath then the initialisation does not fail

```
java -cp scala-compiler-issue-service/target/scala-compiler-issue-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:scala-reflect-2.12.16.jar:scala-compiler-2.12.16.jar:scala-library-2.12.16.jar -Dloader.main=org.example.ServiceAPIApplication org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

The 3 scala jars used are included in the project. They are fetched from maven repository using

```
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.12.16/scala-reflect-2.12.16.jar
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.12.16/scala-library-2.12.16.jar
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.12.16/scala-compiler-2.12.16.jar
```

Passing the jars via classpath solves this issues but is causing problems in other parts of the application

Comment: also asked on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/1avd4eb/facing_object_scala_in_compiler_mirror_not_found/